# uiscrollview can not be dragged in ios8 in arm64

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i have a photo viewer app. 
Scrollview is the main view. ZoomView is the subclass scrollview for its zoom in and out.

Now it works fine in ios8 in armv7 on iphone6. however, it behaves strangely in ios8 in arm64 on iphone6. It is not be dragged when browsing some images.

Is this a bug on ios8 in arm64? how to fix it?

Comment: Have you done some sanity checks like confirming the contentSize is larger than the scroll view's frame? (& similar) Also, in Xcode 6 you can explode the view hierarchy (a la Reveal) and get more specific details about what's actually on screen. I'd do that first. Finding the reason that scrolling is disabled should point you in the direction of why it's happening in one case and not another.

Comment: @GnarlyDog, thanks for your tips. Fixed it! Add self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0) in ZoomView.BTW, the Reveal you mentioned is very very cool ! I love it now! ^_^